# Hacer un click en un enlace con otro boton

Tags: html, jquery, css

quiero solicitar su apoyo para poder realizar click en un enlace cuando le de click a un boton, ya lo intente con trigger pero no se si lo estoy haciendo bien. les dejo imagenes para ver si me pueden apoyar.

[image: Este es el enlace que quiero que se seleccione el que esta marcado en azul]

[image: y el otro es el boton que al seleccionarlo simulara el click en el enlace marcado en azul en la primera imagen.]

Utilice Jquery, el id del enlace de la primera imagen es #prueba y el id del boton es #Siguiente1, les dejo el codigo de como lo hice en JQUERY.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Siguiente1').click(function(){
      $('#Siguiente1').find('#prueba').trigger('click');
      $('#Siguiente1').removeClass('active')
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0});
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no se si entendí bien tu pregunta, pero si lo que quieres hacer es como un trigger de click a un enlace al hacer click en un botón, es de la siguiente forma:

```
$(function(){
   $("#idBoton").click(function(){
      $("#idEnlace")[0].click();
   });
})
```

espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: no de que es un gusto, lo que pasa es que soy nuevo contestando aquí, y ya he leído la sección de cómo responder, pero por ejemplo en este caso creo que mi respuesta es puntual, que crees que le haría falta para mejorarla. Saludos

Comment: Lo mejor es preguntar al OP Y sugerir agregué información necesaria para comprender lo que necesita, ya que en ocasiones podemos responder algo que el usuario no requiere.

Comment: o ya entiendo, muchas gracias

Comment: muchas gracias amigo !! si me sirvio

Comment: de nada bro, un gusto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente poner el botón dentro de una etiqueta `a` a la cual le asignarías el `href` y listo:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com"><button>Siguiente</button></a>
```

Generalmente en los framework como Bootstrap, también se utiliza `a`,  para botones con enlace, algo así más o menos:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="AQUI-URL" role="button">Siguiente</a>
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button">Siguiente</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !! lo que pasa es que el botón esta hasta abajo de la pagina y el enlace, esta arriba en la pagina como parada de tren

Comment: @MarioEstrada No entiendo, ¿lo que quieres es algo que te lleve a donde está el botón? ¿O quieres que el botón te lleve a un apartado de la misma página?

Comment: si amigo, lo que quiero hacer es que el boton de abajo en el footer, realice la misma función (en cuestión de estilos) que realiza el enlace de arriba

Comment: @MarioEstrada no entiendo a qué te refieres con *en cuestión de estilos*. Lo que se entiende al leer la pregunta es que quieres que el botón hagan la función de link (que dirija a otro sitio cuando se haga clic en él).